# Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext' in asp .net core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, rider

I made a project with 5 Class libraries in asp .net core 5.
'ApplicationDbContext' class is in the 'Data' Class library and ny models are in the 'Model' class library. when I run 'add-migration' in Package Manager Console, it works properly but when I run 'dotnet ef migrations add' in console, it shows me this error: 'Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext''.

Comment: add verbose in command, the verbose will display all steps of the execution.

Comment: Probably you are missing package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Nuget packages needed：

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.13">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.13">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

1.Open the package management console: Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Console

2.cd {path where your csproj file resides}

3.Now type dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration

Comment: Thank you for your response.  My problem is solved, but the solution I followed was different from yours.